# Why is the .to_s method needed in Crystal when converting user input to an integer?

Tags: ruby, string, crystal-lang

I'm getting started with Crystal, and I've run into something I don't understand. I've written a simple program to demonstrate, which takes a number from the console and adds one.

**Ruby**

```
# Add one program.
puts "Enter a number."

number = gets

number = number.to_i

puts "You entered #{number}. #{number} + 1 = #{number + 1}"
```

**Crystal**

```
# Add one program.
puts "Enter a number."

number = gets

number = number.to_s.to_i # Why is to_s needed?

puts "You entered #{number}. #{number} + 1 = #{number + 1}"
```

As you can see, the programs are nearly identical, however, in crystal I must take the input from the console and convert it to a string before it can be converted into an integer.

What I want to know is:

- What is being returned by gets in crystal?
- Is there another way to do this without chaining methods?

This may seem like a basic question, but it's still early days for crystal, and documentation is sparse.

**Error**

```
Error in example.cr:6: undefined method 'to_i' for Nil (compile-time type is (String | Nil)) (did you mean 'to_s'?)

number = number.to_i # Why is to_s needed?
                ^~~~

================================================================================

Nil trace:

  example.cr:4

    number = gets
    ^~~~~~

  example.cr:4

    number = gets
             ^~~~

  /usr/share/crystal/src/kernel.cr:105

    def gets(*args, **options)


  /usr/share/crystal/src/kernel.cr:105

    def gets(*args, **options)
              ^

  /usr/share/crystal/src/kernel.cr:106

      STDIN.gets(*args, **options)
            ^~~~

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:574

      def gets(chomp = true) : String?


  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:574

      def gets(chomp = true) : String?
               ^

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:574

      def gets(chomp = true) : String?


  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:574

      def gets(chomp = true) : String?
          ^~~~

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:575

        gets '\n', chomp: chomp
        ^~~~

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:604

      def gets(delimiter : Char, chomp = false) : String?
          ^~~~

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:605

        gets delimiter, Int32::MAX, chomp: chomp
        ^~~~

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:618

      def gets(delimiter : Char, limit : Int, chomp = false) : String?
          ^~~~

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:619

        raise ArgumentError.new "Negative limit" if limit < 0
        ^

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:632

        if ascii && !decoder && (peek = self.peek)
        ^

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:633

          if peek.empty?
          ^

  /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:634

            nil
            ^
```

Comment: What makes you think it is needed? What there an error message without? What did the error message say?

Comment: Updated question to included error message.

Comment: Hi Aaron, May I know what OS are you using ?

Comment: Fedora 29 Workstation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases `gets` will return a String, but it is possible that it returns `nil` too.

This isn't an issue in Ruby, because in your example you will ever have `nil` returned at runtime and even if you had, there is [`NilClass#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i) in Ruby which always returns `0`.

But the Crystal compiler checks object types upfront and therefore makes sure that your code can handle all possible return types. Unfortunately, in Crystal, there is no `to_i` method on [`Nil`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.27.2/Nil.html) yet and therefore you get the compiler error:

```
undefined method 'to_i' for Nil (compile-time type is (String | Nil))
```

Comment: Nil does not equal zero. More often than not you wouldn't want such an implicit conversion. `nil.to_i` returning `0` can easily lead to mistakes. In Crystal the compiler warns you about nilable values and asks to treat them explicitly.
If you want the integer conversion for `nil` to result in `0`, you need to write that explicitly, for example using `number.try(&.to_i) || 0`.

Answer (score 4):

When running either program, try giving Ctrl+D (EOF) as input. Is the program behaving as you expected?

Crystal is protecting you against these kinds of programming mistakes by making you handle all the possible types a method may return. A more correct version of the program could for example be:

```
print "Enter a number: "

number = gets.try &.to_i?
if number
  puts "You entered #{number}. #{number} + 1 = #{number + 1}"
else
  puts "Please enter a valid number"
end
```

Note: `String#to_i?` returns `nil` when the conversion fails, rather than raising an exception as `String#to_i` does.